# Getting empty dataframe after filtering rows

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to filter rows if at least one of the strings below is included in a column `Text`:

```
list_house=['house','apartment','home','cottage']
```

I have done as follows:

```
list_house=['house','apartment','home','cottage']

df_low=df(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower()).copy()
df_fil=df_low[df_low['Text'].isin(list_house)]
```

However, I am not sure it selects rows which contains at least one of them or rows which contains all these strings (my resulting dataframe is empty, and actually I would expect some results).

Example of dataframe:

```
Text 
my house is bigger than yours
I bought a small cottage a few years ago in UK
So you live in an apartment in the city centre. Lucky you! I live in a small house in the countryside.
I like your dogs.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

This filters-in if one of the words exists:

```
df = df[df['Text'].str.contains('|'.join(list_house))]
```

This filters-out if one of the words exists:

```
df = df[~df['Text'].str.contains('|'.join(list_house))]
```

Comment: Yes, it worked great. May I ask you why isin was not working?

Comment: isin - compared full strings and not part of strings - like you need here